# pyspark join with multiple conditions for different rows in in table dfs

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to join two tables based on some conditions in pyspark

I have 2 dataframe (GR_df and HK_df) for table A and table B
there are three columns which are common in both the dataframes.

GR_df.columnx = HK_df.columnh,

GR_df.columny = HK_df.columni,

GR_df.columnz = HK_df.columnj

now, join will be perform based on the join conditions mentioned below:

joincond1 = (GR_df.columnx = HK_df.columnh & GR_df.columny = HK_df.columni & GR_df.columnz = HK_df.columnj),

joincond2 = (GR_df.columnx = HK_df.columnh & GR_df.columny = HK_df.columni),

joincond3 = (GR_df.columnx = HK_df.columnh & GR_df.columnz = HK_df.columnj),

joincond4 = (GR_df.columnx = HK_df.columnh),

If there is only one matching row for joincond1 for each value of columns in GR_df and HK_df
then write that to final df

If there is multiple rows return by joincond1 for each value of columns in GR_df and HK_df
then write distinct records to final df

If there is no matching row for a value in GR_df and Hk_df need to change the condition to joincond2 and so on till condition 4

If a record doesn't satisfy any condition that record will be skipped.

I know I need to iterate over dataframe rows but I am not sure How I can write a logic in pyspark or spark-sql for this problem can anyone help me.

GR_df-

```
columnx columny columnz Other columns

 1        a       aa      -
 2        b       bb      -
 3        c       cc      -
 4        d       dd      -
 5        l       uu      -
```

HK_df -

```
columnh  columni columnj Other columns

 1         a       aa         -
 2         b       zz         -
 3         m       cc         -
 4         i       jj         -
```

final df -

```
columnh  columni  columnj  columns_GR_df  columns_HK_df

   1       a        aa         -              -
   2       b        zz         -              -
   3       m        cc         -              -
   4       i        jj         -              -
```

Comment: Could you please add sample data and expected output based on this sample.  The sample data should get at least one record for each of your mentionned cases. You can read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: *"If a record doesn't satisfy any condition that record will be skipped."* looks like an inner join. *"I know I need to iterate over dataframe rows..."* -- it doesn't seem row-wise iteration is required.

Comment: @Steven, I don't really have the output but all I want is to not skip any record if I would perform join based on condition1 and for some records condition1 is false and condition2 is right. The join will skip those recods. which I don't want.

Comment: @samkart, yes we need to perform inner join. for "it doesn't seem row-wise iteration is required."  -- since for some record condition1 is true and for some record condition2 is true and so on I need to check for all the records in df.

Comment: @okm1234 That's your question. If **YOU**, as OP, you cannot create sample dummy data, how are we supposed to do it as we don't even know your true usecase? How are we supposed to test the code you ask us to produce ?

Comment: @steven I have tried to provide some dummy values for both df in final_df each row represent the different join condition.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for an inner join, with the conditions combined by the or operator. To drop the duplicates after, we use distinct() after the join:

```
output_df=GR_df.join(HK_df, joincond1 | joincond2 | joincond 3, "inner").distinct()
```

Depending on what you want to happen when both cond1 and cond2 are satisfied (exclusive or?), your join condition may become:

```
(joincond1 & ~joincond2 & ~joincond3) | (~joincond1 & joincond2 & ~joincond3) | (~joincond1 & ~joincond2 & joincond3)
```